# How webpack.config.js work in react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack.config.js

I saw **react + express** project code [here](https://github.com/jonghyeon-lee/calyfactory-blog-source1), start project just using this codes.

- rm -rf build public/bundle.js
- ./node_modules/.bin/babel server --out-dir build
- ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --progress
- node ./build/main.js"

But I can't find how to read/execute `webpack.config.js` command. Who read this code? and how it works?

Comment: `webpack` reads this file and you seem running it on 3rd line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack reads `webpack.config.js` [by default](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#usage-with-config-file), unless you explicitly tell it to read another config file by using the `--config` argument, *e.g.*:

```
webpack --config another.config.js
```

In your case, this command reads the `webpack.config.js`:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack --progress
```

Comment: Ahh! I misunderstood `--progress` means `Print compilation progress in percentage` just show percentage... Thank you for your response.

Comment: @SooJungChae No problem! Please feel free to accept the answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't execute webpack.config.js. It is a configuration file that webpack will refer to and use when webpack is run. [See this page for more info.](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/)

The build and start scripts in the package.json file for the project you linked to both run webpack. Webpack will then create a bundle.js file according to the information in webpack.config.js.